# How can I use QLPreviewController in iOS to display image or file using http address?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, qlpreviewcontroller

I' m trying to use `QLPreviewController` to display files located in the web by http address.
For example I want it to display image located here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/preview.jpg

In `previewItemAtIndex` I did this:

```
NSString* url = @"http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/preview.jpg";
return [NSURL URLWithString: url];
```

But when I click on the image in my tableview it appears `Loading...` indicator of the `QLPreviewController` which is rotating endlessly and in the log I see this message:`Couldn't issue file extension for path: /wp-content/uploads/2011/05/preview.jpg`

So the question how can I display files in `QLPreviewController` located in the web using `http` address in `NSURL`? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the items yourself and then pass file URLs to the preview controller. The preview controller only deals with the display and user interaction for you.